# Drupal 8: make Taxonomy terms translatable

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

How to translate Taxonomy terms?
I have 2 languages in my site added here: /admin/config/regional/language
I have turned the Types here /admin/structure/types marked "Show language selector on create and edit pages" in "Language settings" of each type.
But I cannot really understand what to do in Vocabulary settings?
I have terms but I cannot see button "Translate" that it was in Drupal 7.
Should I create 2 languages terms separately one from another?
Please give me manual.

Comment: Have you activated Content Translation module ?

Comment: no. I had not activated it before your advice. I activated and after settings on admin/config/regional/content-language I have "Translations" button in every term. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To translate terms of taxonomies, you need to activate the Content Translation module.